# Ansible querying data

Tags: ansible

Ansible is primarily designed for running tasks on remote machines.  I want to use it in kind of the reverse - pull data from a bunch of machines and store it locally.  I love the setup module but right now I'm interested in pulling a list of users - which the setup module doesn't show me.

Also, I want to add this info into a mariadb table.

I can do this project with the shell module but, my question is, is there a better way?

Unless someone can tell me a better practice, I'll use the shell module for two parts: First, I'll simply cat /etc/passwd and register the output from that.  Then, do a local_action shell script that invokes a mysql command to update the table.

I'd love to both pull the data and insert/update the data into my table using standard modules.  But there don't seem to be modules that will do either.

Answer (score 2):

You could use local facts. It is described here https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#local-facts-facts-d

If a remotely managed system has an /etc/ansible/facts.d directory, any files in this directory ending in .fact, can be JSON, INI, or executable files returning JSON, and these can supply local facts in Ansible.

then you get the local facts in json format with this line:

```
ansible <hostname> -m setup -a "filter=ansible_local"
```

For system user facts you could write a shell-script which returns the system user in json format and put this script under /etc/ansible/facts.d . Each time you gather facts from this machine, you have this facts too.

Comment: The local facts thing is neat - but in this case probably not what I want.  Either way, I'm generating the list with a shell script.  With local facts it's a cron job, with the shell module, it will probably take longer but at least I don't have to rely on the remote system being pre-set up and correct.